# Why is make_shared calling move constructor twice? How to avoid it?

Tags: c++, function, pointers, smart-pointers, shared

I have taken look at related questions on Stack Overflow, and from what I understand, the first line in `main()` should call the constructor, and the second line should trigger one call of move constructor (or copy constructor when move constructor is removed).

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

class Node {
public:
    Node()  { cout << "Called contructor\n"; }
    ~Node() { cout << "Called destructor\n"; }
    Node(const Node& other)  { cout << "Called copy-contructor\n"; }
    Node(Node&& other) { cout << "Called move-constructor\n"; }
};


int main(){
    Node a = Node();
    make_shared<Node>(a);
    return 0;
}
```

But the result I'm getting from the above code is:

```
Called contructor
Called copy-contructor
Called move-constructor
Called destructor
Called destructor
Called destructor
```

It seems to me that the copy constructor is called due to parameter passing, and the move constructor is called in the implementation of `make_shared`, is that right? Is it possible to avoid two constructor calls when calling `make_shared` (using pass by reference of pointer for instance)? Is there any ways to get a `shared_ptr<Node>` with just one constructor call in total?

My compiler version:

```
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple clang version 12.0.5 (clang-1205.0.22.11)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin20.5.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

The code was compiler using default arguments: `g++ test.cpp`

Comment: @rawrex By outputting before and after `Node a = Node()`, it seems that that line only triggers one constructor call.

Comment: `Node(const Node&& other)` -- get rid of the `const`. A const rvalue reference is not doing you any favors here, since you can't actually move from it.

Comment: Which language version are you using? C++17 should never receive a move constructor call thanks to mandatory copy elision, and I would not expect you to see this in any compiler with optimizations enabled. Also I'm not able to [reproduce this with gcc](https://godbolt.org/z/jGqP4fqh7).

Comment: `a` is an lvalue and will invoke the copy-constructor by default. The move constructor is only called when the argument is casted to an rvalue reference using `std::move()`. Try: `std::make_shared<Node>(std::move(a));`. Also, `Node(const Node&& other)` is a wrong way to define a move-constructor. Use `Node(Node&& other)`

Comment: Apple Clang is a strange and terrible beast. Consider using a more normal compiler, like actual gcc or actual clang.

Comment: @RaymondChen Removed it, but the issue is not solved

Comment: @HTNW But I don't think this behavior is implementation-dependent.

Comment: I don't know much about Apple clang, but why do you use `g++ test.cpp` while gives the version of clang? By the way, can you reproduce your output in [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/hjPdbMYP1) by choosing a proper compiler and corresponding compiler options?

Comment: @xskxzr The compiler version info is the output of `g++ --version` on my computer, I am also curious about why g++ gives version of clang.

Comment: @DonnyChan But you assume Apple Clang is a valid implementation to begin with :). But seriously: when I compile this with Apple Clang without `-std=c++11` on my machine I get a big warning saying "rvalue references are a C++11 extension". That's basically compiler-speak for "I do not claim to correctly implement this behavior". *Always listen to compiler warnings!*

Comment: @DonnyChan `g++` gives a clang because a lot of build software out there calls `g++` instead of `c++` to compile C++ code (e.g. maybe to ensure the presence of certain extensions). But clang (at least attempts to) implements all those extensions too, so it is provided under both the standard `c++` name and the `g++` name because it *does* satisfy those interfaces.

Comment: @HTNW True, and I just assumed that warnings do not affect execution result. My bad, *Always listen to compiler warnings!*

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the result only occurs when using `g++ test.cpp` while the default language version is below c++11. When compiled using `g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp`, the output is:

```
Called contructor
Called copy-contructor
Called destructor
Called destructor
```

Which abides by the standard.

I think a possible explanation is that when the compiler detected c++ syntax, it doesn't change to the corresponding language version, but instead use some kinds of "trick" to circumvent compiler errors, but that doesn't follow language standard.